# When I assign sex to an animal, does it become li / ŝi?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

I have only seen words like *virkoko* or *kokino* in sentences where they were a direct subject or object, I don't recall seeing either referred to by a pronoun. Would that still be *ĝi* or should I use *li* or *ŝi* accordingly? Or is either permissible?

A related question is whether a neutral word for an animal like *ĉevalo* is invariably *ĝi* or can become one of the other two if said animal is very familiar to the speaker (e.g., has a name that's manifestly masculine / feminine), without needing the *vir-* or *-in-*.

Examples:

> 1. La kokino ne plu donas ovojn. Ni kuiru supon el [ŝi/ĝi].
> 2. Tio estas mia ĉevalo. [Li/ĝi] nomiĝas Rufus.

Citations in context are very welcome.

Comment: Great question! I've been wondering the same thing. Seems like Zamenhof proposed gxi but that people follow their own preference. I can imagine that gxi is more common in a case like 1 and sxi/li in cases like 2. In the end, I think you'll be understood either way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Zamenhof's intuition was that human beings could be *li, ŝi,* or *ĝi*, but that animals are always *ĝi*.

> *Kiam oni parolas pri bestoj, mi konsilas ĉiam uzi nur la senseksan pronomon “ĝi”, — ne sole kiam (en la plimulto da okazoj) la sekso de la priparolata besto estas por ni indiferenta, sed eĉ en tiaj okazoj, kiam ni parolas precize pri la sekso de la besto. En la tre maloftaj okazoj, kiam la precizeco povas nepre postuli, ke ni montru la sekson de la besto per la uzata pronomo, la teorio ne malpermesas al ni uzi la vorton “li” aŭ “ŝi” sed en ĉiuj ordinaraj okazoj mi konsilus uzi la pronomojn “li” kaj “ŝi” nur por homoj.*
>
> When one talks about animals, I advise the use only of the sexless pronoun *ĝi* — not solely when (as in the majority of cases) the sex of the animal under discussion is a matter of indifference, but even on those occasions when we are specifically talking about it. In the very rare situations, when precision absolutely requires us to show the sex of the animal by the pronoun, theoretically we are not forbidden from using *li* or *ŝi*, but in all ordinary cases I would advise reserving *li* and *ŝi* for human beings.
>
> *Lingvaj Respondoj:* Respondo 35, *La Revuo*, 1908, Majo

However, many of the first Esperanto authors preferred to follow the usual procedure in European languages, more or less using *li* and *ŝi* as a way to grant personhood to animals when the situation seems to call for it (e.g. in fables, or for animals with personal names).

So the standard pronoun for an animal is *ĝi*, but *li* and *ŝi* are unlikely to be objected to.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it either way.

From *Fratoj Grimm*

- *“Refreŝigu vin. La bovino ne donados lakton, **ŝi** estas maljuna bruto, **ŝi** povas taŭgi nur kiel tirbesto aŭ en buĉejo.”*

From *Malnova Testamento*

- *Kaj oni forbruligu la bovinon antaŭ liaj okuloj: **ĝian** felon kaj **ĝian** karnon kaj **ĝian** sangon kune kun **ĝia** sterko oni forbruligu.*

Answer (score 4):

When the sex is not known, you use **ĝi**

> Ĝi is used principally with animals and objects. Zamenhof also prescribed it to be the epicene pronoun for use when the sex of an individual is unknown. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_reform_in_Esperanto#Extending_the_range_of_an_existing_pronoun

When the sex is known, you also use **ĝi** according to the tekstaro. There are several examples of **Kokino** being described as **ĝi.**

Side Note: Zamenhof used **ĝi** even when talking about children.